# PCIe SSD vs SSD vs SAS - which is best for Database?

Tags: raid, ssd, performance-tuning, sas

Since I am going on shipping soon I wonder which generally will mostly boost the database performance ?

The bridge question is - which will boost mostly a database which having a lot of random block readings and deleting records ?

in a single drive performance :

1. OCZ 240GB PCI Express RevoDrive 3 X2 SSD
2. INTEL 240G SSD 530
3. 15k SAS Raptor

and the most interesting - the performance with the same drives in RAID 10 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCIe Flash will offer significantly better overall bandwidth than SSD or HDD therefore should provide better sequential IO, this may not play as big a part in random IO as you might think but you should still see a degree of improvement over regular SSD, both of which will be very significantly better at this than HDD.

Obviously cost/GB comes into play but that's your call.

Bear in mind that some PCIe Flash disks aren't bootable.

Comment: These are very useful hints, Chopper3. Thank You ! :)